# Autofac self register TypedNamedAndKeyedServices

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac, caliburn.micro

I have a simple system that displays different screens (WPF) depending on the type of **Molecule** the user selects. To accomplish it I am using Caliburn.Micro together with Autofac as Ioc Container.

A simple naming convention is expected:

**[MoleculeName] <--> [MoleculeName]ViewModel --> [MoleculeName]View**

Caliburn.Micro provides the view/viewmodel convention and my aim is to replicate the convention for the Molecule<->MoleculeViewModel part.

Each Molecule is represented by a type and inherits from **IMolecule**

```
public Interface IMolecule {...}
```

IoC is provided by AutoFac and the following works just fine:

```
private void ConfigureMoleculesLibs(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
{
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  // get assemblies
  var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

  // register molecules
  builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IMolecule>())
    .AsSelf();

  // register molecules view models
  builder
    .RegisterType<H2SO4MoleculeViewModel>()
    .Keyed<Type>(TypeOf(H2SO4Molecule));
  builder
    .RegisterType<HClMoleculeViewModel>()
    .Keyed<Type>(TypeOf(HClMolecule));
  builder
    .RegisterType<H2oMoleculeViewModel>()
    .Keyed<Type>(TypeOf(H2oMolecule));

}
```

so that the following is allowed:

```
public class MoleculeWrapperViewModel : Screen
{
    public delegate MoleculeWrapperViewModel Factory(IMolecule molecule);

      public MoleculeWrapperViewModel(
        IIndex<Type, Screen> moleculeScreensLookup, 
        IMolecule molecule)
    {
        this.MoleculeViewModel = moleculeScreensLookup[molecule.GetType()];
    }

    public Screen MoleculeViewModel { get; private set; }
}
```

Is there a way to register the Keyed Types automatically by matching names with their corresponding ViewModels in the same way Caliburn does between Views and ViewModels?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use a bit of reflection here to iterate through all the molecule types and invoke the corresponding `AutoFac` generic method

You'd need to use your molecule types to generate your typenames:

```
var viewModelTypeName = moleculeTypeName + "ViewModel";

Type yourViewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelTypeName); // Not 100% on the syntax here, don't have VS open :P

Type type = typeof(ContainerBuilder);
MethodInfo miGeneric = type.GetMethod("RegisterType");

MethodInfo mi = miGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(yourViewModelType);

mi.Invoke(...) // etc
```

Obviously it's a little more complex since you are chaining methods (not sure what `RegisterType` returns - probably a type registration object?) and you would have to provide this for the generic methods on the return object of the first call etc

Have you tried an approach like this yet?

Not sure if `AutoFac` supports anything like this out of the box - but essentially this is all CM is doing (but with some regex magic and probably less generics?)